# Remove focus from AG-Grid

Tags: javascript, focus, ag-grid

I'm using AG Grid on a website. When the user clicks a cell, it is focused and gets a blue outline.

I need to remove this focus when the user clicks certain other elements on the site, but I don't know how to do it. Is there a method or property to set for that?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following snippet to your css

```
.ag-cell-focus, .ag-cell {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Example - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xO5N5u84U8n4HgK5

Answer (score 5):

> Angular2+ <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JqTP1lieNfmWHe9VV4zU?p=preview)</kbd>

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    let body = document.body;
    body.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
      let container = this.agGrid._nativeElement;
        if (!container.contains(e.target)) 
        {
          this.gridApi.clearFocusedCell();
        }
    })
}
```

> JavaScript <kbd>[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YYp3cnPUeT75ItAEhxNv?p=preview)</kbd>

```
var body = document.body;
body.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    let gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid')
    if (!gridDiv.contains(e.target)) 
    {
        gridOptions.api.clearFocusedCell();
    }
})
```

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev, I suppose you are doing something wrong, cuz both samples work as expected.

Comment: I'm using chrome and the blue border still shows for both examples

Comment: so, read the main question again and again, and if isn't clear after all, the solution is for CLICK-OUTSIDE the grid. (for you case click selection could be configured over ag-grid settings)

Comment: @un.spike Hi, This is not working when i am using mat select component in ag grid. Example - [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Eb3QPdvvn98pqJiHbIw?p=preview) Please change dropdown value, value wont change because of this.

I've used this code



`const body = document.body;
    body.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
      const container = this.commonAgGrid.nativeElement;
      if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
        this.gridApi.clearFocusedCell();
      }
    });`

Comment: @VishalMittal Please create a new question and post the link here cuz your question is a little bit different and would require different solution I suppose

Comment: @un.spike here is new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260806/remove-focus-from-aggrid-when-click-anywhere-outside-grid-if-using-matselect-po)

Answer (score 1):

Apple below code to the global style.css file

```
    .ag-cell-focus {
        --ag-range-selection-border-color: transparent !important;
 }
```