# Remove Focus from AgGrid when click outside the ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using AG Grid on a website. When the user clicks a cell, it is focused and gets a blue outline.
I need to remove this focus when the user clicks outside the selected element.

```
const body = document.body;
body.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    const container = this.commonAgGrid.nativeElement;
    if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
        this.gridApi.clearFocusedCell();
    }
 });
```

But this is not working when I am using mat select component in ag-grid. Example- [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Eb3QPdvvn98pqJiHbIw?p=preview)

Please change the dropdown value, the value won't change because of this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here what you need to understand:

1. clicks `listener` should be implemented inside your custom component, *cuz only withing this component you can bind listener for tracking
   click-outside event*
2. `listener` should be implemented inside `ngAfterViewInit` method cuz of `@ViewChild` rendering lifecycle
3. `@ViewChild` requires to get `element` and his `scope` - for outside-click tracking possibility

So you need to have `ViewChild` - bound to your template (inside custom component)

```
@ViewChild('yourElementRef') public yourElementRef:ElementRef
```

Then, bound this property `yourElementRef` to the template (tag (div, form, whatever) should be HTML based - not directive from third party libraries - cuz reference could be missed)

```
template: `
    <mat-card>
    <form #yourElementRef class="container" tabindex="0" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)">
    ...
```

*again if you put `#yourElementRef` in `<mat-cad>` - native element reference would be missed*

And the last thing is tracking itself

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    let body = document.body;
        body.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
        let container = this.yourElementRef.nativeElement;
        if (!container.contains(e.target)){   
            this.params.api.clearFocusedCell();
        }
    })
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/LpeyZ7xYbH1gwRZG)</kbd>

> *P.S: this is a solution for `selection` reset **ONLY**, on exact this example - values (models) doesn't update properly (cuz it's just wrong implemented)*

Comment: ok. That means i have to write this `ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    let body = document.body;
        body.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
        let container = this.yourElementRef.nativeElement;
        if (!container.contains(e.target)){   
            this.params.api.clearFocusedCell();
        }
    })
}`  in every custom components? 
and about the values (models) does not update properly - I picked this example from Ag-Grid demo site so can you please tell me how can i fix this also?

Comment: again the model binding is a little bit out of this question, create a new one xD

Answer (score 2):

Try this option,

```
stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **(focusout)** event listener built in to angular:

In your mat-editor-one.component.html:

```
<ag-grid-angular #commonGrid style="width: 100%; height: 450px;" class="ag-theme-material"
             [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
             (focusout)="focusOut()"
             [modules]="modules">
```

And then in your mat-editor-one.component.ts:

```
focusOut () {
this.gridApi.deselectAll()
 }
```

This will deselect all rows when click outside the grid.

Comment: This does not work. The (focusout) binding is called on every click both inside and outside of the grid, and gridApi.deselectAll() only deselects rows, not the cell being edited as asked by OP. @un.spike's answer has the correct api call